# Programatically check symbols loaded with assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, debug-symbols

I am loading an assembly with its corresponding symbol file (.pdb) using the `Assembly.Load(byte[], byte[])` method. As part of my unit testing I want to verify that the symbols have been loaded successfully.

Is there any way to programmatically verify this from the resulting Assembly object?

Answer (score 0):

Via [Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki) (.Net API on top of DIA)

Via [DIA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx) (COM API)

<s>Via DebuggableAttribute</s>

Comment: Thanks for the response, however this will only partially address the issue - indicating whether the loaded assembly was built in Debug mode. I need a way to check whether the symbol store was successfully loaded along with the assembly.

Comment: I understand, see my revised answer.